# Diferentes maneras de denominar fuegos

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

Como se dice:

- Fire (as in a forest fire)
- Fire (as in your fireplace at home)
- Fire (as in a light for a cigarette)
- Fire (as in a camp fire)
- Fireplace (the kind in your house)

thank you so much!  i love this website!

Comment: You have asked 5 distinct questions here. Please ask one question per post. And be sure to do sufficient research *before* asking. That means you should consult an English/Spanish dictionary for each word *first*, and ask us only when you still have doubts.

Comment: Gracias para la ayuda!

Answer (score 3):

In Spanish we have `Fuego`, `Lumbre`, `Fogata` y `Hoguera`, among others.

`Fogata` is something that you can start in the forest, like a camp fire to roast marshmallows or burn weeds. Is not big.

`Hoguera` is a big fire. Think of the bonfires of Saint John or burning a witch in a stake. A fire of that size is called `Hoguera`.

`Fuego` is the most common and generic word for the fire element. You can refer with that word to almost everything, from *El fuego de la chimenea* <sub>(The fire in the fireplace)</sub>  to the fire that is devastating a forest (by the way, that would be called an *incendio*. *Incendio forestal*, if is in the forest and just *incendio* if is a building. *Chimenea* is Spanish for *fireplace*).

`Lumbre` is a smaller fire, used to cook or to heat the place in the old houses (the `lumbre` used to heat the place would be considered smaller than the fire in a fireplace). With that word you can describe not only a household fire, but the material that use are using to burn ("Tráeme algo de lumbre para el fuego, que se está apagando" <sub>Bring me some lumber for the fire</sub>).

I have heard some people use `lumbre` when they ask you to light their cigarette (probably because the fire in a lighter or match is so small) but the most common word for that is `fuego` too.

> Perdona, me das fuego? <sub>excuse me, could you light my cigarette?</sub>

So, sorted by size

- Incendio
- Hoguera
- Fuego (en la chimenea) o fogata (en el campo)
- [Lumbre](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=cGI7IWd46DXX2x4P153c)
- Llama (for a lighter, matches or a candle. Kudos to @Paloma for this one [see comments])

Comment: gracias para la ayuda!

Comment: una cosa más.  Yo se madera is wood pero come se dice "firewood" para la chimenea en la casa??

Comment: Se suele usar ["Leña"](http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=E5VryNCkXDXX28tlr7yR)

Comment: En Chile, si la fogata a leña está adentro de una casa se le dice _fogón_. Si es de carbón se le dice _brasero_.

Comment: @Rodrigo, muy buen apunte.

Comment: Para el caso del mechero, la cerilla o la vela, quizá incuiría «llama», que, si bien no es fuego propiamente dicho, y tampoco es «fire» en inglés (es «flame»), también se usa, ya que es un fuego muy pequeño.

Answer (score 2):

Incendio forestal, o incendio en general es un fuego sin control.

Chimenea u hogar, el lugar donde se hace fuego para calentarse en la casa.

Fogón para cocinar.

Fogata en el campamento.

Hoguera para quemar o incinerar cosas o personas. En hogueras quemaban a las brujas y a los herejes en la Edad Media.

Fuego, fósforos o encendedor para los cigarrillos. También lumbre, mecha y otras formas populares.

Comment: Gracias para ayudarme!